# AppleScript for counting messages in Inbox fails with "Can't get mailbox"

Tags: mail.app, applescript

Here is my first attempt at an AppleScript program, which met with ignominious defeat:

```
tell application "Mail"
    tell mailbox "INBOX"
        count messages
    end tell
end tell
```

It compiled, but when I ran it, I got the error message

```
error "Mail got an error: Can’t get mailbox \"INBOX\"." number -1728 from mailbox "INBOX"
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong, and if there is a short introduction to AppleScript, written for someone used to programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is understandable in what you expect should be the syntax.

Each account has it's own mailbox named "INBOX"

In Mail the mailbox  **inbox**  is the reference to the top level inbox that shows contents of all other inboxes named "INBOX"

2 examples:

Example 1

```
tell application "Mail"
    set inboxes to first mailbox of every account whose name is "INBOX"
    set messageCount to 0
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in inboxes

        set this_item to item i of inboxes
        if this_item is not missing value then
            set thisCount to (count of (messages of this_item))
            set messageCount to thisCount + messageCount
            log thisCount
        end if
    end repeat

end tell
log messageCount
```

Example 2

```
tell application "Mail"
    set messageCount to (count of (messages of inbox))
end tell

log messageCount
```

Both return and log the same total.

But example 1 also logs the individual count of each "INBOX"

A good place to start is to read through:  [AppleScript Fundamental](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html)s

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Mail"
    -- This returns count of messages across all inboxes
    set countA to count (messages of inbox)

    set countB to count (messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account "david")
end tell

return {countA, countB}
```

In AppleScript Editor, hit command shift o to open the application dictionary. AppleScript 1-2-3 and the Definitive Guide are good places to start.